# Python : Copy only those .avi files from one directory to another which are within a file name range given in command line argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, file-handling, shutil

I've different directories which contain `.avi` files in given format:

```
2021-03-06
---17 15 33.avi
   17 16 33.avi
   17 17 33.avi

2021-03-07
---19 43 57.avi
   19 44 57.avi
   19 45 57.avi

Retrieval
```

The user will give directory name from which he wants to copy the file, start file name and end file name as an argument. Example:

```
python copy.py -f "2021-03-07" -s "19 43 57" -e "19 44 57"
```

After running this a new sub-directory should be created inside Retrieval which will be same as the start file name, where the `.avi` files should be copied.

Expected Result:

```
2021-03-06
---17 15 33.avi
   17 16 33.avi
   17 17 33.avi

2021-03-07
---19 43 57.avi
   19 44 57.avi
   19 45 57.avi

Retrieval
---19 43 57
   ---19 43 57.avi
      19 44 57.avi
```

[Note : Only videos which are within the start and end file names should be copied including the given file names]

This is the script I've been able to write so far :

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
import argparse
from pprint import pprint 



ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-d","--startTime",  type=str, required=True,
                help="Start time of video")
ap.add_argument("-r","--endTime",  type=str, required=True,
                help="End time of video")
ap.add_argument("-f","--folder",  type=str, required=True,
                help="Folder name for which videos are to be merged")

args = ap.parse_args()

source='drive://'+args.folder+'//'
dest='drive://Retrieval//'+args.startTime+'//'
files = []
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        files.append(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        files.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
pprint(files)

if os.path.exists(dest):
    print("this folder exit in this dir")
else:
    dir = os.mkdir(dest)
    for f in files:
        shutil.copy(f,dest)
        print("done")
```

The issue with above code is that it copies all files from source to the destination folder.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for editing, I don't have much knowledge on formatting questions properly on stackoverflow. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Sure thing buddy. But please note that your question is lacking focus. You can read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre] to get more advices. *"I'm completely lost on what to do ahead"* is not a valid Stack Overflow question... Your question need to focus on a very specific programming problem

Comment: Understood, I'll update my question.

Comment: you could try to compare strings `if "19 43 57" <= name_without_ext <= "19 44 57":` and it should works. Problem can makes only if you use native chars in names instead of numbers.

Comment: @furas, seems to be perfect solution if filenames always have same format and no additional validation required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform pattern search on files you can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). In example above for all operations with file paths I've used [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and there's [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) which provides interface between `pathlib` and `glob`.

So, to retrieve all needed files from folder we can use next pattern: `[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9].avi`. It will match all `.avi` files where name will contain 3 2-digit numbers separated by space.

Your filenames contain time and I'd recommend you to use [`time.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime) or [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert *startTime* / *endTime* arguments and filenames into corresponding time structures which we will be much easier to compare.

Also I've added some basic data validation and messages to your code, here is final result:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from pathlib import Path
from time import strptime
from shutil import copy2

ap = ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-s", "--startTime",  type=str, required=True,
                help="File name with Start time of video")
ap.add_argument("-e", "--endTime",  type=str, required=True,
                help="File name with End time of video")
ap.add_argument("-f", "--folder",  type=str, required=True,
                help="Folder name for which videos are to be merged")

args = ap.parse_args()

root_path = Path(r"drive://")
filename_format = "[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9].avi"
time_format = "%H %M %S"

src_path = root_path / args.folder
dst_path = root_path / "Retrieval" / args.startTime

# source folder validation
if not src_path.is_dir():
    raise FileNotFoundError("Provided folder doesn't exist")
# destination folder vaidation
try:
    dst_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
except OSError:
    raise ValueError("Can't create folder:", dst_path)
# start/end time validation
try:
    min_time = strptime(args.startTime, time_format)
    max_time = strptime(args.endTime, time_format)
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Invalid start/end time")

for file in src_path.glob(filename_format):
    try:
        parsed_time = strptime(file.stem, time_format)
    except ValueError:
        print("Skipped:", file)
    else:
        if min_time <= parsed_time <= max_time:
            copy2(file, dst_path / file.name)
            print("Copied:", file)
        else:
            print("Skipped:", file)
```

Comment: I've tested the code and its working perfectly according to my requirement. Although I've a question. Will this be efficient if lets say I've thousands of videos inside the source folder.

Comment: @saurabh first try it and you will see if it is efficient for you.

Comment: @furas I've tried with 20 videos in the source folder, and gave range of 10 video files. By that I can conclude it'll not be very efficient when working with huge number of files as it'll take very long to copy the files. Although the solution provided by Olvin does its job as expected.

Comment: @saurabh, you can't boost file copying, it doesn't depend on which solution you'll use because it's handled on OS level. The one possible way to boost it is to *move* files instead of copying. If my answer helped you, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer.

Comment: @Olvin Yes i agree, although using ffmpeg may speed up this process, I'll leverage your script to use that approach. Thanks for this solutuon.